# Can I display filter settings in the ReactAdmin app bar?

Tags: react-admin

Is it possible to display elements of my current filter in the ReactAdmin app bar?

E.g. I have a team filter in order to show sales results for a given team in a company. This bit is all working. The filter ends up in the route as the team id, not name. I'm not sure if it's possible to change that, and I probably don't want to anyway; but all the same I would like to display the selected team *name* from the filter in the app bar.

I've already set up a custom app bar, but the info I need doesn't seem to be available as props to the app bar.

I can see in Redux Tools that teams by id have been pre-loaded, under `admin\resources`; but I'm not sure that the layout of these pre-loaded items is officially supported? Nor if there's any official timing as to when they're loaded? (These must be there because they were loaded for the filter, so logically I guess(??) that the one I need must be there when a filter value has been selected....)

Then, as far as I can see, to get the current filter settings I'd have to extract things from the `router` part of the state as well.

I could try connecting my custom app bar to Redux and extracting the above items. I think I could get this working - but it has a strong code smell. The smell of 'will break with any ReactAdmin updates', perhaps mixed with the smell of 'accessing state from the wrong place, at the wrong time'!

Is there a cleaner, more official way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented the 'not officially supported' approach which I suggested in my own question. It works fine, but - fair warning - for all I know it might stop working after an update to ReactAdmin.

If I work out a more officially supported approach or if I manage to commit anything from this back to the ReactAdmin project I'll update this answer.

So, here is a custom layout:

```js
// CustomLayout.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Layout, AppBar } from 'react-admin';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import getFilterValue from './getFilterValue';

const useStyles = makeStyles(
  theme => ({
    title: {
      flex: 1,
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
      whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
      overflow: 'hidden',
    },
  }),
  { name: 'RaAppBar' }
);

const CustomAppBarUnconnected = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  const { title } = props;
  return (
    <AppBar
      {...props}
    >
      <Typography
        variant="h6"
        color="inherit"
        className={classes.title}
      >
        { title }
      </Typography>
    </AppBar>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  let team = getFilterValue(state, 'teamId', 'teams'); //, 'name');
  let previousMonth = getFilterValue(state, 'previousMonth');
  let title = `${team ? team.name : 'Company'} Sales. ${previousMonth ? `Previous month = ${previousMonth}` : 'Nothing to see here'}.`;
  return {
    ...props,
    title
  };
};

const CustomAppBar = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(CustomAppBarUnconnected);

export const CustomLayout = (props) =>
  <Layout
    {...props}
    appBar={ CustomAppBar }
  />;
```

Apply this in your ReactAdmin app using`<Admin layout={CustomLayout}>`. Here's some example output:

[image]

Most of the custom layout is just boilerplate required to get a custom app bar which looks like the default one: it passes children to the standard AppBar, applying the formatting required to make the title look just like the standard title.

> If you want the default title to appear along with your custom title, add `<span id="react-admin-title" />` where you want it to appear (presumably, somewhere next to `{ title }`).
>
> If you also want to more thoroughly re-arrange the app bar then (following the [ReactAdmin documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-layout)), you would need to make a new custom AppBar class from scratch, starting from the original ReactAdmin [AppBar class](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/layout/AppBar.js). Then just link it to Redux as I have done above.

The key change in this custom layout is that the AppBar is now connected to Redux, which means that in `mapStateToProps` we can call the new function `getFilterValue`:

```js
// getFilterValue.js
const getFilterValue = (state, source, resource, field) => {
  let value = undefined;

  if (!state || !source) return value;
  
  const filterJSON =
    state.router &&
    state.router.location &&
    state.router.location.query &&
    state.router.location.query.filter;

  if (filterJSON) {
    let filter = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(filterJSON));

    let id = filter && filter[source];

    if (id !== undefined) {
      if (!resource) {
        value = id;
      } else {
        const data =
          state.admin &&
          state.admin.resources &&
          state.admin.resources[resource] &&
          state.admin.resources[resource].data;

        if (data) {
          value = data[id];
          if (field) {
            value = value[field];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return value;
};

export default getFilterValue;
```

Depending on which arguments you pass to `getFilterValue`, you can:

- Get a raw item from the filter: `(state, source)`
- Map a raw item id from the filter to an object already fetched from the API: `(state, source, resource)`
- Map the id from the filter to an item and then extract a named field from the item: `(state, source, resource, field)`

`undefined` is always returned if the required value doesn't exist; e.g. if you're not on a page with the requested filter, or if the filter hasn't been applied yet by the user, or if you've made a typo in any of the arguments.